# selecting specific json objects from large log file in python 3.x

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to load a large log file (13+ gb) of json objects. I'm able to dump the whole file in the ram but the process is very slow and I don't need all the objects at once.

What is the best way to loop through the file and select json objects within a specific date range? My code currently looks like this:

```
path = //logfile


import json

records = []
line_number = 0
file = open(path, encoding="utf8")
for line in file:
    try:
        line_dict = json.loads(line)
        clean_dict = {"username": line_dict["username"], "language": line_dict["language"],
                     "key": line_dict["key"], "page_url":line_dict["page_url"],
                     "session": line_dict["session"], "timestamp": line_dict["timestamp"],
                     "value": line_dict["value"]}
        records.append(clean_dict)
    except (KeyError, ValueError, NameError, UnicodeDecodeError):
        continue
    else:
        line_dict = json.loads(line)
        clean_dict = {"username": line_dict["username"], "language": line_dict["language"],
                     "key": line_dict["key"], "page_url":line_dict["page_url"],
                     "session": line_dict["session"], "timestamp": line_dict["timestamp"],
                     "value": line_dict["value"]}
        records.append(clean_dict)
file.close()
len(records)

Output: 25695470
```

I'm working with a jupyter notebook.

Comment: You can catch multiple exceptions at once: `except (KeyError, ValueError, NameError, UnicodeDecodeError): continue`

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)